# Detect each active instance of a widget

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, wp-cron, twitter

Is it possible to detect each active instance of a particular widget?

As part of a plugin I'm working on, I want to run a for each loop on each widget instance

Each widget is a Twitter feed and the plugin allows me to register each Twitter feeds name.

Eventually I want to add in a minutes option in to each widget, then I can tie the plugin in to wp cron, but that's a development job for later.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at using transients for your data.
Using transients would also take care of needing to use cron to update the data.

Transients are an under utilised function of Wordpress and can save considerable loads on resources as sites get busier.

Vee